# How to check there are only 2-4 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex, I'm trying to check whether there's only 2-4 characters used after a `.`. At the moment, i got it working to detect when its less than 2 characters but after 4 characters, it still deems it as successful. How can I fix this? This is what I have written down:

```js
/.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the dot (`.`).

```
/\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Answer (score -1):

`.` is the control character in RegExp, you should to escape it:

```
/\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

And, to ignore case, add the `i` flag:

```
/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```